How can I measure rodent local field potentials (LFPs) with single electrodes (not tetrodes)?
We have platinum-iridium single microelectrodes lying around in the lab with 125/150µm tip diameters and I'd like to use one or two of them to measure hippocampal/brainstem LFPs. All the protocols I've found either use tetrodes or multi-electrode arrays. I understand that single electrodes are not ideal because of the noise, but is there a specific protocol I could use? I've been searching for a very long time. Am I missing something?

People measure with single electrodes all the time, you just have a very remote ground so what you measure is more like an "EEG". It's not a matter of protocol, it's a matter of physics. You can only measure what physics lets you measure.

@BryanKrause Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I'm a little new to this. I understand that the signal between the recording electrode and ground gets subtracted. Are you suggesting that I need at least two electrodes in close proximity to measure LFPs? Could you clarify please?

You can place your ground as far away from your recording site, somewhere you don't expect any input to matter for your system. Typical choices are in the bath (in vitro or in vivo) or the animal's skin. Make sure you are recording in differential mode.

@RobertS The further away your ground, the less "local" your measurement is. In many cases like vkehayas says a reference/ground under the skin is considered suitable.
